# Is there any point in unregistering cells for reuse in TableView/CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm making thin custom TableView- and CollectionView-subclasses with a few quality-of-life-features, like auto-registering cells for reuse, so I don't have to make that code every time for the rest of my life.

I generate the `cellIdentifiers` on the run, and register them. I thought "why not also implement auto-unregister", because a cell obviously might be reloaded away to never return. But I can't actually find out how..

Based on the documentation about registering cells for both [tableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register) and [collectionView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618083-registernib?language=objc), it says the following:

> You may specify nil for nib if you want to unregister the nib file
>   from the specified reuse identifier.

However, if I (in my subclassed UICollectionView) try to use `self.register(nil, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)` I get the error

```
Ambiguous use of 'register(_:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)'
```

I'm have no idea why, but I'm thinking it might be because both of these functions:

```
register(_ cellClass:AnyClass?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:String)
register(_ nib:UINib?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:String)
```

they're ambiguous when attempting to pass `nil` as the first parameter.

So - what does the documentation actually expect me to do? Can I cast the nil to anything to help it pick either of these?
And - is unregistering really necessary? I've never done it before, and I couldn't find much online about it..
How much does it "cost" to keep a cell registered? I'm guessing it'll be more expensive to actually "unregister" a cell than it is to just leave it registered, as unregistering will be an actual operation - but I might be wrong here..

I understand that I can register different cells with the same identifier, which would essentially unregister the previous registration, but if I'm 100% sure I'll never use the same identifier for different cells, do I need to unregister?

Answer (score 2):

I've never unregistered a reusable cell in my life, so I've no idea if it's worthwhile or not, but if you really want to, you'll have to be more specific with your code. You're correct in that it can't interpret the method properly.

```
tableView.register(Optional<UINib>.none, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cheese")
```

Will allow the compiler to work out which of the two methods you're using.

Answer (score 2):

You can downcast `nil` to `UINib?` to let the compiler know which `register` you are referring to:

```
self.register(nil as UINib?, forCellWithReuseIdntifier: identifier)
```